# Pushing a navigation controller after a modal view controller is presented

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uitabview

I have a tab view controller which has a button like so and when it gets pressed a modal appears:

```
PostViewController *post = [[PostViewController alloc] init];

// [self.navigationController pushViewController:post animated:YES];

// Presentation
[self presentViewController:post animated:YES completion:nil];
```

When the modal is done I want to dismiss it and push a new view controller like so:

```
ProfilesViewController *profile = [[ProfilesViewController alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
```

But I can't do it in the post vc as its a modal. How do I do this?

Comment: Why do you need to present something and dismiss it before even appearing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try using `completionBlock`.

`CompletionBlock` is called when presentViewController is done.

```
PostViewController *post = [[PostViewController alloc] init];
[con presentViewController:post animated:YES completion:^{
    ProfilesViewController *profile = [[ProfilesViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:profile animated:YES];
}];
```

More information about `presentViewController:animated:completion:` [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/Documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIViewController_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/presentViewController:animated:completion:)

> completion : The block to execute after the presentation finishes.
>   This block has no return value and takes no parameters. You may
>   specify nil for this parameter.

Comment: Okay so it pushes it behind the modal?

Comment: It pushes into the navigationController stack.

Comment: If you want dismiss your modal before, you can add `dismissViewControllerAnimated:completion:` using the completionBlock too

Comment: One more question, once I dismiss post can the post data be displayed in the ProfilesViewController? So does the profile view controller run when it becomes visible?

Comment: When you dismiss a ViewController, it `releases all data` inside. So you must provide all args you want to keep to the new VC. Hope this answer your question

Answer (score 1):

Dose your tab view controller embedded in a UINavigationController?
If you have not, you of course cannot use self.navigationController.